# Which Linux should I chose for penetration testing and networking

Tags: linux, security

I am fairly new to networking and penetration testing, however, I'm really interested in the field and would like to know which distribution of Linux would be best to work with for security testing...and why. I've heard that Backtrack is probably the best, but I'm not sure, any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly suggest Kali, because you already get a lot of tools for that purpose, and it is still quite easy to handle (and you get a lot of tutorials in addition).